# How to custom cake bake in CakePHP v 3.0.0-RC2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-bake

After run `composer.json` I go edit :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\src\Console;
C:\xampp\mysql\bin;
C:\xampp\php;
```

In `run cmd` go in htdocs run `cake bake`

```
C:\xampp\htdocs>cake bake
```

> 'cake' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

I can not find folder `/lib/cake/Console` in CakePHP v3.0.0 RC2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to do it?

```
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\FolderCakePhp\bin
```

and run:

```
cake bake model all
```

I think what you want to do is it!

Answer (score 1):

Since CakePHP 3.0.0, the CakePHP core is installed as a Composer dependency of your project and it no longer resides in `lib/Cake`. It is now under `vendor/cakephp/cakephp` instead (after running a `composer install`). Also see [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#installing-cakephp) on this.

Also, the bake command is now [a Plugin](https://github.com/cakephp/bake) that you will need to include manually if you want to use it.

```bash
php composer.phar require --dev cakephp/bake:dev-master
```

I would recommend to start your project with the [App template](https://github.com/cakephp/app). This already has the bake plugin in it's composer.json file. Just check it out locally:

```bash
cd /your/dev/folder
git clone https://github.com/cakephp/app.git yourApp
```

Then install everything at once with Composer:

```bash
cd yourApp
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar install
```

This will give you the bake shell (in the `bin` folder of your project) and the framework itself all in one.